# Why google chart not display when add in runat="server"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I have this div:

```
 <div>
    <asp:Literal ID="lt" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>  
<div id="chart_div1"   style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

It run well and can show the barchart very fine.
The  bindchart() function I put in my codebehind:

```
.. str.Append(@"<script type=text/javascript> google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*corechart*]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
...
str.Append(@"<script type=text/javascript> google.load( *visualization*, *1*, {packages:[*corechart*]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

..
str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));");
    str.Append(" chart.draw(data,{isStacked:true, width:900, height:350, hAxis: {showTextEvery:1, slantedText:true}});}");
...
    str.Append("</script>");
    lt.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',').Replace('*', '"');
    ...
```

But when I add

```
"runat="server"
```

to id = "chart_div1"

```
 <div>
    <asp:Literal ID="lt" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>  
<div id="chart_div1"  runat="server"  style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

then I can see the div appear as blank and cannot see the graph !
Why it is so strange like that ? I need to put runat="server" so that I can recognize the id in my code behind for further process. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's asp.net auto naming which turns your "chart_div1" into something like "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chart_div1". If you're targeting ASP.NET 4.0 you can switch this off in page directive, just set ClientIDMode="Static". This will produce ID's exactly as you have them in your controls.

Comment: you have <@Page ...> directive in the top of .aspx-file

Comment: I don't have that, only have: <%@ Control Language="c#" Inherits="Syntegra.Manufacturing.WMCCM.Web.UI.Companies.Companies" Codebehind="Companies.ascx.cs" %> or <%@ Register ...

Comment: ah, sorry, you can use it in the control itself
<div ID="chart_div1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">

Comment: I tried that but it still not show the graph. I can see the div with empty content. Not really know why is it so. Is there anyway around, that I can get rid of "runat=server" but still can point to that ID in my code behind?

Comment: Using debug I can see that the string can quote the ID correctly:var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1')) I don't know why the graph is not visible, I can see the data also input correctly, and I made the div.visible = true also. It really strange why can't the graph appear ?

Comment: Yeap, it strange. It seems we are searching in wrong direction. What for do you need the runat="server" attribute. As I can see you simply don't need them. You didn't use it as a server control itself. Use it's id ("chart_div1")  as a constant in scripts.

Comment: If I do not have runat="server" then in my code behind it cannot recognize this id of this div

Comment: Yes, in the script may not need "runat=server" to work, but I implement some buttons and it will call function in code behind, this function call the id to make it visible or invisible. Can we make it invisible or visible at ascx file? Then I no need runat=server.

Comment: I found another way around. Although your answer doesn't help to solve the problem but it could be the only reason I could think of now... So I will close my question by accepting your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

change this line

```
  str.Append(" var chart = new     google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));");
```

TO

```
str.Append(" var chart = new     google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('<%=chart_div1.ClientID %>'));");
```

reson behind this is when you apply runat server attribute to your element that element becomes server side and asp.net framework appned some string to it so id of that element changes

Comment: -1 The way you place it its a string and not convert the name to rendered id. You just print a string.

Comment: @user1314404 This is the correct way: `str.AppendFormat(" var chart = new     google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('{0}'));", chart_div1.ClientID);`

Comment: The `<%= ... %>` fragment works only when it will be processed by the ASP.Net engine, like in the markup in an aspx page. It does not work when you just output a string from code, like this.