# Is there anyway to hide a div in ascx file alone?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net

I have a `<div>` in an ascx file:

```
<div id="chart_div1" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Is there any way I can click a button like :

```
<input id="Button29" type="button" value="Hide It!" onclick="dosomething" />
```

so that every time I click this button it will hide the div above ?
But I do not want to use code behind to make it happens because if I include `runat="server"` to my `<div>`, it will not be able to load the google chart point to it. ([Pls refer to this post for better understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282248/why-google-chart-not-display-when-add-in-runat-server/25282429?noredirect=1#comment39434377_25282429))

So, any way that I can hide my div when clicking that button without changing my `<div>`?

Comment: you can try `onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('chart_div1').style.display = 'none'"`

Comment: you can place that div in an asp:placeholder and then hide the placeholder when you click the button (if you are wanting to hide it server side)

Comment: Hi Grundy, your comment is my answer! what is the opposite of 'none' when I want to make it visible by another button ? I tried 'yes' and 'true' not working.

Comment: @user1314404 you can use `'block'`, or empty string

Comment: Yes, that is perfect solution. Can you form an answer so I can accept or how is the proper way to show my appreciation to your help!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for solving this little problem you can use [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) api, and set property [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) as you wish.

first: get div with `id="chart_div1"` - `document.getElementById('chart_div1')`
second: set display property - `document.getElementById('chart_div1').style.display='value'`, where `value` from list of allowed values.

> none | inline | block | list-item | inline-block | inline-table | table | table-cell | table-column | table-column-group | table-footer-group | table-header-group | table-row | table-row-group | flex | inline-flex | grid | inline-grid | run-in

for adding inline js to html using protocol "javascript:"
so for hide div you need add this `onclick`

```
<input ... onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('chart_div1').style.display='none'" />
```

for show - this

```
<input ... onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('chart_div1').style.display='block'" />
```

Comment: Much appreciate your help! Thank you.